# How to quickly switch between extended desktop and Eyefinity on ATI cards?

Tags: eyefinity, amd-catalyst, extended-desktop

Eyefinity is great for games but extended desktop is better for normal work. How do I set up quick switching between those two modes?

I've heard that it can be achieved using "Profiles" in Catalyst Control Center - I've found something called "Presets" in the latest 11.x version but can't figure it out (settings not being stored and applied properly). Can someone provided step by step instructions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick was to first set up everything and *then* create a preset.

Comment: Yep, that's it.  You should now "accept" your answer so this question moves from the list of open questions to being resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you can simply use the shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

`Extend` will give you the extended mode and `Duplicate` will give you the eyefinity mode.

Comment: I had this working before in Windows 7 but not on my new 8.1 install. Is there a trick that I overlooked?